# PyUnit : Failed to read XML-RPC request: Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence

Tags: eclipse, windows-7, python-unittest

When I run pyunit from eclipse, the PyUnit view is not updated and I have the following error

```
Finding files... done.
Importing test modules ... done.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 tests in 0.000s

OK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev.debug_2.4.0.2012020116\pysrc\pydev_runfiles_xml_rpc.py", line 131, in run
    self.server.notifyCommands(commands)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1224, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1575, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1264, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1297, in single_request
    return self.parse_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1473, in parse_response
    return u.close()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 793, in close
    raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
Fault: <Fault 0: 'Failed to read XML-RPC request: Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.'>
```

Do you have any idea what cause this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by insufficient access rights to the eclipse directory (read only access).
I grant permissions to the installation directory (modification), and now i don't have this error.

Answer (score 0):

I also came across this error using pyunit with eclipse.

My problem was, during a test, trying to print a utf-8 string to the pyunit console. Converting the string solved the problem:

Problem code:

```
print(my_Utf8_String)
```

Fixed:

```
print (unicode(my_Utf8_String).encode('utf8'))
```